# React Router Still Renders Previous Page after Routing to New Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am making a landing page for my site, which will have 3 components - header, main and footer, only for the landing page. The header component is just a nav bar with a logo on the left and sign in button on the right.

When the sign in button is clicked, I render a login route using the router but the problem is the previous components of Landing page (Header, Main and Landing) are also rendered with the new routed Login component.

Here's my `App.js` file where Landing is inserted.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import Landing from './components/Landing/Landing';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Landing/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

and in Landing component I have this setup:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import Header from './Header';
import Main from './Main';
import Footer from './Footer'

class Landing extends Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div className="container__landing">
                <Header/>
                <Main/>
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Landing;
```

Here's my header component, for brevity I have left out the other two components:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router';
import Login from '../auth/Login';

class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <header className="header">
                    <div className="header__nav">
                        <p>STRONG LIVE</p>
                        <button className="sign_in">
                            <Link to="/login">
                                Sign In
                            </Link>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
                </header>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
export default Header;
```

The login component is rendered but it's placed inside the landing component along with the header and other present components.

I want the login page to be stand-alone and without the header, which is currently above it. 
I have seen some tutorial where they have used the `props.history.push('/path)` but in React Dev Tools, none of my components have these props.
How do I switch components on button click? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the URL will match the `path` property of your `<Route>` component, a.k.a. when you'll be on the `/login` page, React router will render your `<Login>` component **at the place in your component tree where the corresponding `<Route>` is**.

The problem is that your `<Router>`, and more specifically your login `<Route>` are *inside* the `<Landing>` component.

If you want the login page to be rendered without header, you should place both the `<Landing>` and `<Login>` components inside a `<Route>`, *next to each other*. Then, render them conditionally using React Router's `<Switch>`component :

> A `<Switch>` will iterate over all of its children  elements and only render the first one that matches the current location. (see the [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/basic-components/route-matching) for details)

Here's an (untested) example :

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        {/* Render the login component alone if we're on /login */}
                        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />

                        {/* Otherwise, render the Landing component */}
                        <Route component={Landing} />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your point makes sense to me. Can you share with me a proper tutorial explaining how to route components from navigation bar list items and also on button click

Comment: Your code works. Thanks. I have earlier tried wrapping Landing component with ````withRouter```` but no desired output

Comment: Please share good resources with me as the tutorials I've seen are outdated cos some components have been split up from ````react-router-dom```` and moved to ````react-router```` so I can't follow the changes along with the examples online

Comment: Do I need to declare all my routes in routes file or I can use them in the components where they're needed only?

Comment: I am personally using the [React router quickstart](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) when I need informations. The only components you really need are `<Router>`, `<Route>` and `<Switch>`. You can declare your routes in any component, but they need to be inside the `<Router>`, that's why we usually put it in the root `<App>` component.